# How to get the difference between two date time values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a hard time in getting the difference between two datetime values.

For example:

```
col1               col2 
----------         ----------
11-04-2011         22-05-2033
12-05-2010         24-06-2045
```

and the result set should be something like this:

```
11-01-2022

12-01-2035
```

Thanks to all,

Shashra

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by difference. For me, if you are finding the difference between year 2033 and 2011 the answer should be 0022, not 2022. Maybe if you gave an example as to what you were using this for we could be more helpful.

Comment: of course you are right year should be 0022 but what if the company wants the difference in those years. I mean to say the difference between those two years are 22 but its is in 21st century right. So we need to get the century and the year(the difference).

Comment: Um, no. The difference has no century. It's basic math. The year 2033 minus the year 2011 is 22 years, not 2022. Your question makes absolutely no sense, and neither does the explanation in your comment. :) I think you need to go back and have your client/company explain what they want again, because you have to have misunderstood. The only way that the answer could possibly be 2022 is if the question is "How do I find the number of years between 2011 and 2033, divide that difference by 2, and add it to the year 2011?"

Comment: oh ok... actually its an insurance company an they need the time left between those years. the col2 is a maturity end date and the col1 is maturity start date. so they need the time left between those maturity dates..

Comment: @Shahsra, I am still unclear as to what you want. What would be the difference between 2033 and 1980? How would you go about finding that?
Just saw your latest comment. So it sounds like you want the difference between the dates to result in the amount of time left? So 22-05-2033 and 11-04-2011 would result in 22 years, 1 month, 11 days as the answer?

Comment: I am  sorry I realized the problem now . thanks for your help. I really appreciate for your this help and the doubt which you asked me...thanks again to all.

Answer (score 1):

Using `DATEDIFF`, find out how many days are between the 2 dates.

Half this value.

Then use `DATEADD` and add half the days to the first date.

```
declare @d1 datetime
,@d2 datetime

set @d1 = '11/4/2011'
set @d2 = '22/5/2033'

SELECT DATEADD(d, (DATEDIFF(d, @d1, @d2)/2), @d1)
```

Therefore, in your query, you would use:

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, (DATEDIFF(d, col1, col2)/2), col1)
FROM [Table]
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your client is confused about the difference between a date (a *particular* year, month and day) and a duration (a *quantity* of years, months, days).  Subtracting one date from another results in the latter, not the former.

Such confusion is more common than is often believed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want to do that one solution is to:

1. Get the day, month and year values of each date to different variables;
2. Subtract each day, month and year variables;
3. Add 2000 years to the year resulting value;
4. Make a date with the resulting day, month and year.

You might need to use a [cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) to fetch each row individually.